# Adding object variables from a list

Tags: c#, list, object

the objects belong to a list which calls an external object class

I would like to simplify the following line of code

```
int TotalObjectVarN3 = (Object1.variable3 + Object2.variable3 + Object3.variable3 + Object3.variable3);
```

Comment: If the objects were in a collection (e.g. a `List<MyClass>`), you can use LINQ: `myCollection.Sum(o => o.variable3)` or a corresponding loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one does it using LINQ

int TotalObjectVarN3 = MyList.Sum(o => o.variable3):

Answer (score 2):

[This overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sum?view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_Sum__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Int32__) of `System.Linq.Enumerable.Sum` should work nicely for you:

> Computes the sum of the sequence of Int32 values that are obtained by invoking a transform function on each element of the input sequence.

In this case, the "transform function" would be a `Func<TSource, Int32>` that returns the value of the `variable3` property for the item (e.g. `obj => obj.variable3`).

You could use it like this:

```
int TotalObjectVarN3 = new []{ Object1, Object2, Object3 }.Sum(obj => obj.variable3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Select` is an option followed by the `Sum` method. Select Projects each element of a sequence into a new form.

```
list.Select(i => i.variable3).Sum();
```

More about `Select` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=net-5.0